# REST url - user by id and name

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have two actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Users/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser(int id)

[HttpGet]
[Route("Users")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser(string name)
```

When I am trying to call /Users?name=aaa I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

What am I doing wrong?

**-----------
I have noticed I have one more action:
[HttpGet]
public async TaskGetOffers()
This was the reason, sorrry**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve data from query string, you need to use FromQueryAttribute

```
// e.g. Users/10
[HttpGet]
[Route("Users/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser([FromRoute] int id)

// e.g. Users?name=John
[HttpGet]
[Route("Users")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser([FromQuery] string name)
```

Comment: I have noticed I have one more action: [HttpGet] public async TaskGetOffers() This was the reason, sorrry and thank you

Answer (score 1):

try with the below code

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Users/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser([FromQuery] int id)

[HttpGet]
[Route("Users")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser([FromQuery]string name)
```

Comment: I have noticed I have one more action: [HttpGet] public async TaskGetOffers() This was the reason, sorrry and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you change from

```
[Route("Users")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser(string name)
```

To

```
[Route("Users/{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult>GetUser(string name)
```

And also provide type in your route

```
[Route("Users/{id:int}")]
```

Comment: OK, but how can I do it in query string?